# How I can filter a value corresponding to a specific key in a string?

Tags: javascript

In my JS code, i have string as

```js
s = "{\"selector\":{\"owner\":\"tom\"}}";  // originally this is a query response
```

I want to extract the value of 'owner' which is tom in another variable, s1.

What would be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to get it as an obj first.

Comment: If it's a JSON string, you can use `JSON.parse(s).selector.owner` to get the `owner` infomation

Comment: try this => `let s = "{\"selector\":{\"owner\":\"tom\"}}" console.log(JSON.parse(s).selector.owner)`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I have tried this .... can you help identify the problem?
I have query results fetched from database into s 

`res.status(200).json({response: s.toString()});`

This gives me 
`{"response":"{\"colour\":\"black\",\"make\":\"Tesla\",\"model\":\"S\",\"owner\":\"Adriana\"}"`

now when I try to do this 

`console.log(json.parse(s.toString()).selector.owner);`

it gives me error 

`{"error":{"message":"Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined\n`

Comment: just did, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `not` selecting the right `properties` when accessing your `response` data. Also you do not need to use `toString` in `JSON.parse`. Because your `response` is already a `string` data.

You want to convert `string` data by using `JSON.parse`

**Demo:**

```js
//Response # 1
let findOwner = "{\"selector\":{\"owner\":\"tom\"}}" 

//Parse Data
let parseData = JSON.parse(findOwner)
console.log(parseData.selector.owner) //Tom

//Response # 2
let findOwner2 = "{\"response\":{\"colour\":\"black\",\"make\":\"Tesla\",\"model\":\"S\",\"owner\":\"Adriana\"}}"

//Parse Data
let parseData2 = JSON.parse(findOwner2)
console.log(parseData2.response.owner) //Adriana
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert your data to an object use obj = `JSON.parse(s)`

Then `obj.selector.owner` Or
`obj["selector"]["owner"]` which is the recommended way to get *JavaScript* object values...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for this:

```
function get(path, obj) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((acc, current) => acc && acc[current], obj)
}

const obj = "{\"selector\":{\"owner\":\"tom\"}}"
const parsed = JSON.parse(obj)

get('selector.owner', parsed) // return 'tom'
```